# help installing pcl on ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, installation, pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently trying to install the point cloud library so I can use it's RANSAC features for sphere detection.

There seem to be lots of tutorials about using the PCL with ros but I can't find anything about how to install it.
I've been following the answer to this ros answer:

http://answers.ros.org/question/201516/installing-pcl-for-ros-indigo/

I've added the dependency to my package.xml file so it now looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>sme_awareness</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>Package of Lidar and Camera awareness tools</description>
  <maintainer email="pete.blacker@gmail.com">pete blacker</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <url type="website">http://www.PeteBlacker.com</url>
  <author email="pete.blacker@gmail.com">pete blacker</author>

  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>

  <!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend version_gte="1.7.0">pcl</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf2</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf2_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>dp_ptu47_msgs</build_depend>

  <run_depend version_gte="1.7.0">pcl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libpcl-all-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf2</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf2_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>image_transport</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
  <run_depend>dp_ptu47_msgs</run_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
  </export>
</package>
```

However when I execute the command:

rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y

I get the error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
sme_awareness: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [pcl]
```

Can anyone help me get this up and running?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228800/help-installing-pcl-on-ros-indigo/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're depending on both `pcl` and `libpcl-all-dev` in your package.xml, and rosdep is telling you that `pcl` isn't a valid package or rosdep.

If you look through the [rosdep database](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml), pcl is not listed. It looks like `libpcl-all` and `libpcl-all-dev` are the runtime and build dependencies that will install pcl.

I would recommend that you replace:

```
<build_depend version_gte="1.7.0">pcl</build_depend>
<build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
```

With:

```
<build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
```

(and similar for your run dependency)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-12**:
The code listed on the answer you linked to is a diff: it shows both the old version (`-` and red) and the new version (`+` and green). You **ONLY** need the new parts.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thanks for the reply, this looks good. I'm afraid I've already managed to get this working. pcl had installed find using apt-get the missing link was perception_pcl. When I installed that also using apt-get then it all started working.
TBH your solution looks like it would have been easier!